# Every File absolute URL from base URL in each subdirectory C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to get all the files absolute URL every file in the given base URL (Directory listing is on)
I have tried Regex but its showing folder name only in current directory not going into each subdirectory each file and showing there name?
How can we get a list of string(all absolute url) in every directory of each log file?

I have use this code:

```
List<PathInfo> pathInfos = new List<PathInfo>();
HttpHelper.GetAllFilePathAndSubDirectory("http://example/", pathInfos);
HttpHelper.PrintAllPathInfo(pathInfos);

public static class HttpHelper
{
    public static string ReadHtmlContentFromUrl(string url)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(html);
        return html;
    }

    public static void GetAllFilePathAndSubDirectory(string baseUrl, List<PathInfo> pathInfos)
    {
        Uri baseUri = new Uri( baseUrl.TrimEnd('/') );
        string rootUrl = baseUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

        Regex regexFile = new Regex("[0-9] <a href=\"(http:)?(?<log>.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Regex regexDir = new Regex("dir.*?<a href=\"(http:)?(?<dir>.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        string html = ReadHtmlContentFromUrl(baseUrl);
        //Files
        MatchCollection matchesFile = regexFile.Matches(html);
        if (matchesFile.Count != 0)
            foreach (Match match in matchesFile)
                if (match.Success)
                    pathInfos.Add(
                        new PathInfo( rootUrl + match.Groups["log"], false));
        //Dir
        MatchCollection matchesDir = regexDir.Matches(html);
        if (matchesDir.Count != 0)
            foreach (Match match in matchesDir)
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var dirInfo = new PathInfo(rootUrl + match.Groups["dir"], true);
                    GetAllFilePathAndSubDirectory(dirInfo.AbsoluteUrlStr, dirInfo.Childs);
                    pathInfos.Add(dirInfo);
                }                        

    }


    public static void PrintAllPathInfo(List<PathInfo> pathInfos)
    {
        pathInfos.ForEach(f =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.AbsoluteUrlStr);
            PrintAllPathInfo(f.Childs);
        });
    }

}



public class PathInfo
{
    public PathInfo(string absoluteUri, bool isDir)
    {
        AbsoluteUrl = new Uri(absoluteUri);
        IsDir = isDir;
        Childs = new List<PathInfo>();
    }

    public Uri AbsoluteUrl { get; set; }

    public string AbsoluteUrlStr
    {
        get { return AbsoluteUrl.ToString(); }
    }

    public string RootUrl
    {
        get { return AbsoluteUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority); }
    }

    public string RelativeUrl
    {
        get { return AbsoluteUrl.PathAndQuery; }
    }

    public string Query
    {
        get { return AbsoluteUrl.Query; }
    }

    public bool IsDir { get; set; }
    public List<PathInfo> Childs { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} IsDir {1} ChildCount {2} AbsUrl {3}", RelativeUrl, IsDir, Childs.Count, AbsoluteUrlStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to give us the input page and what you expect the output to be. Right now it's hard to know what the issue is.

Comment: @Enigmativity i want to build a tool which take URL of directory and print each and every log files which are on webserver directory.

Comment: Yes, please give us a copy of the page you're downloading and what the data will look like when it is done. A good question gets answers within minutes of posting. You're isn't good, so far.